# Most of them due to /most of them to

Tags: grammar

India has lost over 2,000 soldiers in the last  three decades, most of them  to extreme and unpre-dictable weather events.

Large laundries face rapid changes most of them due to rising utility costs.

Most of them due to /most of them to, how to identify what to use in a sentence

Comment: I think either (and also "from") could be used in the first sentence. I think the more complete version might be: "India has lost over 2,000 soldiers in the last three decades, most [losses] to extreme and unpredictable weather events."  In the second one you could also replace the "due to" by "from".

Answer (score 1):

The test is whether the sentence makes sense if you remove the words *most of them*. Let's look at your sample sentences:

1. India [lost more than] 2,000 soldiers in the last three decades to extreme and unpredictable weather events.
2. India [lost more than] 2,000 soldiers in the last three decades due to extreme and unpredictable weather events.
3. Large laundries face rapid changes to rising utility costs.
4. Large laundries face rapid changes due to rising utility costs.

Sentence 1 says that the soldiers were lost as a direct consequence of the weather events. A lightning strike that killed the soldiers would qualify, but not a lightning strike that simply disabled the vehicles, leaving the soldiers vulnerable to enemy action. In sentence 2, both qualify.

Sentence 3 says that for large laundries, rising utility costs are changing rapidly. Since *change* is constrained by *rise* (i.e. not *drop*), this means that the costs are *rising rapidly*. This interpretation looks forced and is therefore unlikely to be the intent. Sentence 4 can be read more naturally to mean that rising utility costs have led to rapid changes in something else. For example, they may have had to supplement their profits by introducing vending machines to their shops.

You ask:

> Most of them due to /most of them to, how to identify what to use in a sentence[?]

Use the form "X due to Y" when Y doesn't directly cause X (i.e. Y caused or allowed Z, which in turn led to X). When Y does directly cause X, either form will do.

Answer (score 0):

One could say: Because of rising costs, large laundries face rapid changes.
This sentence has a smoother flow and avoids the clumsy 'due to'.